# How can I stop WIndows Phone 8.1 from continually downloading and installing an update?

Tags: update

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 that I bought used. When I began using it it told me there was a new OS update to be installed. I did that. But after it runs for some amount of hours it will again tell me that there is a new version of the OS to be installed. Is there something I can do to get it to stop re-updating?

Comment: The same update should not be installed over and over. What OS version do you have in Settings > About > More Info? Also, uncheck the box in Settings > Phone Update.

Comment: @NeilTurner I have OS version 8.10.12393.890 . I think the update that was taking place when I asked this question took. It is the first one that sent me a text message after it finished - "Hi there! To find out about the new, fun stuff that's in your Windows Phone 8.1 update, go to windowsphone.com/new

Comment: It seems like your phone was behind on updates, I would recommend you check for updates a few times and install the update. They contain new features and fixes.

Comment: @NeilTurner You mean that if there have been 5 OS updates since a phone was updated, it will do each one, not just the last one? That would explain why it kept repeatedly updating. I did not write down the OS version numbers each time as I should have, to see if they were different versions. My phone has been set to do automatic updates since I got  it.

Comment: Some are cumulative, others are not. So I'd guess you only have a couple of updates to install. That should be it until Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck 'Automatically Download Updates' option under Settings > Phone Update, if you do not wish to download updates automatically.  You can manually check for updates using 'Check for Update' and install when you wish to.